# netsh command to change to static ip only changes my default gateway?

Tags: command-line, static, window, ip, netsh

I'm trying to change my ip address to a static ip addres with the following netsh command:
netsh interface ip set address name="Wi-Fi" static x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0 x.x.x.x 1

But this only changes my default gateway and doesn't affect anything else. Sometimes it doesn't even affect the gateway. The result looks like this:

[image: http://puu.sh/4ouAQ.png]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and explicitly state all the values:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Wi-Fi" source=static addr=x.x.x.x mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=x.x.x.x 1
```